# Multi-DC replication after connection loss

Tags: cassandra

We have 2 DC, which are connected via an instable VPN, which loses connection once every 3 hours.

All data is written to DC A and replicated to DC B.
After one of this "connection loss" events there is data missing (window of the outage affected) on DC B.

My assumption was, that DC B will resume replication after connection has been reestablished and get all the missing data. Is that assumption wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cassandra has following ways for replicating data:

- hints - when `hinted_handoff_enabled` is set to true, the mutations are replayed when nodes are back online, but this happens only inside window defined by `max_hint_window_in_ms` (default is 3 hours), but this may also be affected by per table gc_grace_seconds setting (see [this blog post for details](https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2018/03/21/hinted-handoff-gc-grace-demystified.html)).  But use of hints could be disabled on the per-DC basis (via `hinted_handoff_disabled_datacenters`). Also, hints aren't replayed momentarily, as they are throttled by `hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb` & `max_hints_delivery_threads` parameters.
- repairs - need to be executed explicitly, but could be more effective than hints, especially because you can run it on specific tables;
- read repairs - for multi DC will work only if you're using something like QUORUM for reading the data...

If the hints are enabled, and you still miss the data - check that hints are already replayed, or they are still replaying - [there are metrics](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/metrics.html#hintedhandoff-metrics) that shows how many hints on disk, etc.

If the problem happens periodically, and you can detect it, then maybe explicit repairs will work faster - but in this case you'll need to disable cross-DC hints, so the nodes won't be receiving the data twice...